# Unequal resistive power splitter

Tags: power, rf, power-electronics, transmission-line

I'm looking at a 3-port, unequal resistive power splitter design like the dashed-line box in the diagram.

[image]

1 is the source, whereas 2 and 3 are two loads of impedance, say Z0. All 1, 2, and 3 are connected to the splitter via coaxial cables also of equal impedances; Z1 = Z2 = Z3 = Z0.

Let's say I want to pick resistors R1, R2, and R3 such that only 1% of the power that enters the splitter at 1 goes into port 3. I also don't want any power reflected back to 1, and I want as much power as possible out of port 2. How do I choose R1, R2, and R3? Here's what I have so far:

Since I don't want any reflected power out of port 1, the impedance looking into port 1 has to be matched to Z1 = Z0. Loads 2 and 3 are also matched to Z0, so looking out of ports 2 and 3, I only see an impedance of Z0. Setting the effective input impedance at port 1 to Z0 gives me

R1R2 + R2R3 + R1R3 + 2Z0R1 - Z0^2 = 0.

Further, since I want only 1% of the input power out of port 3, R3 = 9 R2.

How do I proceed after this?

Comment: I agree with your first equation, but the second should probably be \$R_2+Z_0=9(R_3+Z_0)\$ and even then this just ensures the current is split 90% to 10% between ports 2 and 3. This doesn't mean port 3 gets 1% of the *input* power. What about loss in R1? Write a new equation for power in to out for each port, in terns of the resistor values and \$Z_0\$